# how to Convert byte[] to Word of interop object(to a word document)?

Tags: c#, stream, office-interop

i want to save a word document in data base and i do that in this way:

```
  FileStream st = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
  byte[] buffer = new byte[st.Length];
  st.Read(buffer, 0, (int)st.Length);
  st.Close();
  //save Buffer into DB
  //myentityobject.FileContent = buffer;
  //save it
```

but when i want to read it ,i don't how to make a word document from the stream that i get from DB.i tried something like this:

```
 var doc = myentityobject.FileContent;
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(doc as byte[]);
 letterPatternDoc = new Document(stream);
 filePath = @"D:\LetterPatternDocument001.doc";
 object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
 currentApp = new wd.Application();
 currentApp.Visible = true;
 currentDoc = currentApp.Documents.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
 currentDoc = doc;
 currentDoc.SaveAs(ref path, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, false
               , oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,      oMissing, oMissing);
```

but it dosen't work.

EDIT:

i change the code and it work's now,i saved file by filestream,then read it.but i don't know is it a good solution?

```
FileStream fileSream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fileSream);
        bw.Write(FileContent);//filecontent is a byte[]
        fileSream.Close();

       // WordDoc.OpenDocument(filePath);
```

Comment: elaborate on "doesn't work"... what does it do (or not do)

Comment: @ psubsee2003 : As i said,i saved a word document in database and now i want to read and show it in word application.

Comment: What is bw.Write(ViewSource.CurrentItem.LetterPatternDocument.FileContent);
 Is that your own viewer?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this method:
save the file to somewhere,and save the file path to database.when you want to read this file ,you can get the file path from database.hope it can help you:)

Answer (score 0):

Try serializing the document object thereby preserving the state of document and save it in db . While reading deserialize the document object will be again available to you to show .

Answer (score 0):

word isn't able to open a stream, but you can save it, modify it and then after updating in the database, just delete this "temporary" file

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the **FileStream** you can also take advantage of the built-in **WriteAllBytes** static method within the `System.IO.File` namespace.

Here's a brief example (assuming **Interop.Word** is installed and referenced):

```
// byte[] fileBytes = getFileBytesFromDB();
var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllBytes(tmpFile, fileBytes);

Application app = new word.Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(filePath);

// do your stuff    

// convert the DOCX file back to a Byte Array
doc.Close();
app.Quit(); // VERY IMPORTANT: do this to close the MS Word instance
byte[] newFileBytes= File.ReadAllBytes(tmpFile);
File.Delete(tmpFile);
```

For additional info regarding this topic you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/open-edit-word-doc-docx-file-byte-array-c-msword-interop/) on my blog.